Analog of Birkhoff's HSP theorem regarding ultraproducts and elementary sublattices
I am in the process of translating Herrmann's $S$-verklebte Summen von Verbänden [$S$-glued sums of lattices] https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01246623.  His proof of theorem 7.4 runs:

Theorem 7.4. Let n be a natural number. Then the class of all
skeletons of modular lattices of length n is an axiomatic class.
Proof. It is sufficient to show that the class is closed under taking
of ultraproducts and elementary sublattices.  ...

In this context, these lattices are all finite-length. I assume here that "elementary sublattice" means a sublattice that is an elementary substructure of the given lattice in the sense of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_class.
I am familiar with Birkhoff's HSP theorem that a class of abstract algebras is axiomatic iff it is closed under homomorphic images, subalgebras, and direct products.  But though equational classes of lattices are discussed at length in standard references, I have not been able to track down any similar theorem regarding closure under ultraproducts and elementary substructures, either for general abstract algebras, lattices, or finite-length lattices.  Indeed, references to elementary sublattices are quite scarce.
I am hoping that somebody knows a reference to the relevant theorem off the top of their head.

Note that the notion of "axiomatic class" here is different than the one in Birkhoff's HSP theorem. The HSP theorem is about classes of algebras axiomatized by equations (i.e., sentences of the form $\forall \overline{x}\, t(\overline{x}) = t'(\overline{x})$, where $t$ and $t'$ are terms). But here Herrmann means that the class of all skeletons of modular lattices of length $n$ is an elementary class, i.e., the class of models of a first-order theory.
The correct reference is to Frayne-Morel-Scott, as in Noah's answer. But the proof is pretty quick and easy, so I'll give it here for convenience. The key idea is the same as in the ultraproduct proof of the compactness theorem: ultraproducts let us "paste together" structures that realize finite fragments of a theory into a structure realizing the whole theory. In this case, we take the theory to be the elementary diagram of a structure $B\models \mathrm{Th}(K)$, so that $B$ embeds elementarily into an ultraproduct of strutures in $K$.
Let $L$ be a first-order language, and suppose $K$ is a class of $L$-structures which is closed under ultraproducts and elementary substructures. Let $T = \mathrm{Th}(K) = \{\varphi\mid \forall A\in K, A\models \varphi\}$. I claim that $K = \mathrm{Mod}(T) = \{A\mid A\models T\}$, so that $K$ is an elementary class.
Clearly $K\subseteq \mathrm{Mod}(T)$. For the other direction, let $B\in \mathrm{Mod}(T)$. By the closure properties of $K$, it suffices to show that $B$ embeds elementarily in an ultraproduct of structures in $K$. Let $L' = L\cup \{b\mid b\in B\}$, the language obtained by introducing a new constant symbol for each element of $b$. Let $T' = \mathrm{EDiag}(B) = \mathrm{Th}_{L'}(B)$, the elementary diagram of $B$.
Let $P = \mathcal{P}_{\mathrm{fin}}(T')$, the set of finite subset of $T'$. For each $\Delta\in P$, with $\Delta = \{\varphi_1,\dots,\varphi_n\}$, let $\varphi_\Delta = \bigwedge_{i=1}^n \varphi_i$. Note that $\varphi_\Delta$ only mentions finitely many of the new constants, say $b_1,\dots,b_k$. Let $\varphi'_\Delta(y_1,\dots,y_k)$ be the $L$-formula obtained by replacing each constant $b_i$ by a variable $y_i$. Now there is some $A_\Delta\in K$ such that $A_\Delta\models \exists y_1\dots y_k\,\varphi'_\Delta(y_1,\dots,y_k)$, otherwise $\lnot \exists y_1\dots y_k\,\varphi'_\Delta(y_1,\dots,y_k)\in T$, contradicting the fact that $B$ satisfies this sentence and $B\models T$.
Pick $a_1,\dots,a_k\in A_\Delta$ such that $A_\Delta\models \varphi'_\Delta(a_1,\dots,a_k)$, and turn $A_\Delta$ into an $L'$-structure by interpreting the constant symbols $b_1,\dots,b_k$ as $a_1,\dots,a_k$, and interpreting the other constant symbols in $L'$ arbitrarily. Then $A_\Delta\models \varphi_\Delta$.
Having obtained $(A_\Delta)_{\Delta\in P}$, we pick an ultrafilter on $P$ to take the ultraproduct. For each $\varphi\in T'$, let $X_\varphi = \{\Delta\in P\mid \varphi\in \Delta\}$. The family of sets $(X_\varphi)_{\varphi\in T'}$ has the finite intersection property, since $\{\varphi_1,\dots,\varphi_n\}\in \bigcap_{i=1}^n X_{\varphi_i}$. Thus we can find an ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$ on $P$ such that $X_\varphi\in \mathcal{U}$ for all $\varphi\in T'$.
Let $A^* = \prod_{\Delta\in P}A_\Delta/\mathcal{U}$. For each $\varphi\in T'$, if $\varphi\in \Delta$, then $A_\Delta\models \varphi$. So $\{\Delta\in P\mid A_\Delta\models \varphi\}\supseteq X_\varphi\in \mathcal{U}$ and by Łós's theorem, $A^*\models \varphi$. Since $K$ is closed under ultraproducts, the reduct $A^*|_L\in K$. Since  $A^*\models T'$, there is an $L$-elementary embedding $e\colon B\to A^*$. Therefore $B\in K$, as desired.

To expand the details for ignorant readers like myself:  a class of algebras "axiomatized by equations" is the class of algebras which satisfy a set (possibly infinite) of equations, that is, one term equal to another term, universally quantified over all variables.  An "elementary class" is the class of algebras which satisfy a possibly infinite set of first-order statements, which can contain logical connectives and complex quantification patterns.  Thus any class of the first type is a class of the second type.

Keisler's survey on ultraproducts is a good source, incidentally.
This is Theorem 2.13 (and the subsequent comment) of Frayne/Morel/Scott, Reduced direct products. I found out about this result from an answer of Keith Kearnes.
Incidentally, there's another way to attack this. The Keisler/Shelah isomorphism theorem - two elementarily equivalent structures have isomorphic ultrapowers - was proved around the same time assuming GCH, and about a decade later unconditionally (via a vastly more difficult proof); K/S implies that a class is elementary iff it is closed under ultraproducts and ultraroots (= reverse ultrapowers, basically), which in turn implies the result here. But (unless you assume GCH) this is much harder than F/M/S.
